# jQuery.each overwrites posts

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, each, google-geocoder

I use addresses in a Pimcore backend. The addresses go to the geocoder, which will be used to get lat and lon out of the address. After this the lon and lat are stored in the backend (Pimcore). This works pretty well.

The next step is to give out all the addresses so that they are shown on a map in the frontend. Markers are set and the addresses for the POIs are shown. I implemented a link which scrolls to the map, sets the zoom to 16 and centers around the POI.

My problem here is that only the last POI is shown, no matter on what Address link i click (it scrolls to the map and zooms in.. but there is always the last poi shown). This makes me think that somehow my `jQuery.each` overwrites all the points, so that only the last stays. If I `console.log` the lat and lon points they fit and are right for the addresses.

Maybe there is something I oversee or I miss some specific part that is vital in this function. I hope this makes sense to you, if there are some questions or if I am to unspecific let my know and I will explain more. regards, Daniel

```
cw.map.prototype.generateMarkersFromvcard = function () {
    var cwMap = this;
    jQuery('.vcard').each(function (k, v) {
        var id = jQuery(v).data('markerid');
        var vCard = v;

        // TODO: only last address is shown
        var lat = jQuery('.latitude [title]', v).attr('title');
        var lon = jQuery('.longitude [title]', v).attr('title');

        console.log('latitude ' + lat + ', longitude ' + lon);

        // Fallback if lat and lon
        if (lat && lon) {

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var properties = {
                position: point,
                map: map,
                icon: " ",
                labelContent: '<i class="icon-pin map-pin"></i>',
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(24, 48),
                labelClass: "labels" // the CSS class for the label
            };

            // setting the marker to the map
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel(properties);
            cwMap.infowindow(marker, jQuery('.infowindow', v).html());
            markers[id] = marker;
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: and how do you create the address-links?

Comment: lat and lon are the latitude and longitude date from the pimcore backend DB. I get them by sending the addresses to the google maps api. If i console.log lat and lon the right data is printed to the console. My only problem now is that somehow the each loop overwrites all data and only save the last entry. because of this only one address is shown on the map .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you create your infowindow. Some how Google Maps always get the reference to last `marker`.

If you look at this Google Maps example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure

Google try to do the `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()` in a function to avoid this mis-referecing problem; this example would not work if you copy the code from the function, replacing the function call. Look at this example where the issue is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqshut95/

Hope it helps.